# Basic application of Weyl-Character-Formula

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

(I did not find a solution of my problem in any forum so far. Sorry if it exists...)

I am new to Lie-Algebras and representations and actually do not need the mathematical background... I need only to apply the Weyl-Charakter-Formula on $so(5)$ ($B_2$-Type, $\text{rank }(so(5))=2$). In Fulton and Harris 'Representation Theory' they give on p.400 what I think is the same as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula:
\begin{align}
 \text{ch}_{\lambda} = \frac{\sum_{w\in\mathscr{W}} (-1)^{\ell(w)}e^{w(\lambda+\rho)}}{e^\rho \prod_{\alpha\in \Phi^+}(1-e^{-\alpha})}
\end{align}
So far I know/think the following:

$\Phi^+$ is the set of positive roots; I choose the simple roots to be $(-1,1)$ and $(1,0)$, so that the Weyl-Vector $\rho$ is $(0,1/2)$. The Weyl-Group $\mathscr{W}$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $8$. $\ell(w)$ is the lenght of $w$ defined as the minimal number of secessary reflexions of simples roots.

Applying this on $su(2)$ was no problem, but I don't understand the meaning of $e^{\rho}$ and $e^{w(\lambda+\rho)}$. I was told once, that this is defined by $e^\rho:=e^{\rho_1}\cdot e^{\rho_2}$. Is this correct?
Also this should still make sence if $e^{\beta\cdot\rho}$, where $\beta$ is a non-integral number.

Also I am confused by the fact, that the irreducible representation does only appear in $\lambda$, the highest weight in the fundamental Weyl-Chamber (Humphreys' Definition) which in turn is part of the Root-Lattice. Is that correct?

As I said, I just started learning about this, so please keep it as simple as possible. Thanks for any help! I somehoy cannot give usefull tags, so I will saty very general here...

Comment: §16.4.6.4 in Soergel's notes ( http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/soergel/Skripten/XXALLES.pdf ) might help clarify the meaning of the $e^\alpha$ (provided that their meaning on the Wikipedia is the same as in Soergel's notes). Essentially, $e^\alpha$ is just a "wrapper" for $\alpha \in \mathfrak{h}^\ast$ whose purpose is to write the additive group $\mathfrak{h}^\ast$ multiplicatively (i.e., to find a *multiplicative* group isomorphic to the *additive* group $\mathfrak{h}^\ast$). Namely, we let $e^{\mathfrak{h}^\ast}$ denote the ...

Comment: ... set of all $e^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha \in \mathfrak{h}^\ast$. Then, $e^{\mathfrak{h}^\ast}$ becomes a group, as follows: $e^{\alpha} e^{\beta}$ is defined to be $e^{\alpha+\beta}$, and $\left(e^{\alpha}\right)^u = e^{u\alpha}$ for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathfrak{h}^\ast$ and $u \in \mathbb{C}$ (this defines inverses, in particular). Thus, $\left(e^{\mathfrak{h}^\ast},\cdot\right) \cong \left(\mathfrak{h}^\ast, +\right)$ as groups. The reason why we are doing this is that we want to take the group ring of $\mathfrak{h}^\ast$, but working with group rings of *additive* groups is ...

Comment: ... extremely painful (you need the symbol $+$ for two different things), so we prefer to make that additive group multiplicative.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/49908/11619).

Comment: You can think of those $e^\lambda$:s as follows. If $\lambda=n_1\lambda_1+n_2\lambda_2$ (with $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ the fundamental weights), and we declare $X_1=e^\lambda_1$, $X_2=e^\lambda_2$, then
$$e^\lambda=X_1^{n_1}X_2^{n_2}.$$ In other words, those $e^\lambda$:s are just a bunch of placeholdes for compactly describing the character of the module. $\chi_V=\sum_\lambda m(\lambda)e^\lambda$ where $m(\lambda)$ is the multiplicity of the weight in $V$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg is that the intended link? It's in German and 16.4.6.4 doesn't seem to have to do with this... maybe they've been updated since 2015?

Comment: @JonathanRayner: Okay, that's a bad case of link rot. In the current version of XXALLES.pdf, the reference should be §23.1.6.4. Normally, http://web.archive.org would be a good place to look up old references like this one, but the site seems to be down right now. Yes, it's in German, but so is the OP, given her use of spelling like "Weyl-Charakter-Formula" :)

Comment: Okay thanks - I haven't tried web.archive.org before, but that will be very useful.